# Function continuity problem

Tags: calculus, continuity

Let f be a continuous function in the interval $[a,\infty)$, and $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=L$. Then f is bounded.
I've been trying to prove by contradiction but I couldn't manage to prove that if it's not bounded than it has to converge to $\infty$ at some point $x_0$, therefore it is not contionuous. Help?

Comment: "Converge to $\infty$" is ususlly called "diverge" or perhaps "diverge to ,$\pm\infty"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your limit definition:

> A function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ has a limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L$ iff for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that by letting $x > N$ we ensure $\left| \, f(x) - L \,\right|< \epsilon$.

Choose some $\epsilon$. Since you're given that $f$ has limit $L$ at infinity, there is some $N$ so that $f$ is well-behaved beyond $x = N$. In other words, on the interval $(N, \infty)$, we are ensured $\left|\,f(x)\,\right| \le L + \epsilon$ (triangle inequality). But $f$ is continuous on $[a, N]$, and thus must attain a maximum in that interval as well, call it $M$.

So $\left|\,f\,\right|$ is bounded above by $\max\{M, \, L + \epsilon\}$.